# BeautifulSoup: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

I can't avoid the maximum recursion depth Python RuntimeError using BeautifulSoup.

I'm trying to recurse over nested sections of code and pull out the content.  The prettified HTML looks like this (don't ask why it looks like this :)):

```
<div><code><code><code><code>Code in here</code></code></code></code></div>
```

The function I'm passing my soup object to is:

```
def _strip_descendent_code(self, soup):
    sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for code in soup.findAll('code'):
        s = ""
        for c in code.descendents:
            if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                if c.name != code.name:
                    continue
                elif c.name == code.name:
                    if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                        s += str(c)
                    else:
                        continue
        code.append(s)
    return str(soup)
```

You can see I'm trying to increase the default recursion limit but this is not a solution.  I've increased up to the point that C hits the memory limit on computer, and the function above never works.

Any help to get this to work and point out the error/s would be much appreciated.

The stack trace repeats this:

```
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1234, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1255, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 529, in _find_all
    i = next(generator)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1269, in descendants
    stopNode = self._last_descendant().next_element
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 284, in _last_descendant
    if is_initialized and self.next_sibling:
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 997, in __getattr__
    return self.find(tag)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1234, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1255, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 529, in _find_all
    i = next(generator)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1269, in descendants
    stopNode = self._last_descendant().next_element
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 284, in _last_descendant
    if is_initialized and self.next_sibling:
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 997, in __getattr__
    return self.find(tag)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1234, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1255, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 512, in _find_all
    strainer = SoupStrainer(name, attrs, text, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1548, in __init__
    self.text = self._normalize_search_value(text)
  File "/Users/almccann/.virtualenvs/evernoteghost/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1553, in _normalize_search_value
    if (isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, collections.Callable) or hasattr(value, 'match')
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message and stack trace you're seeing.

Comment: The error is "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". It looks to be a bug as per here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1757057. But i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If that bug is the problem, the solution should simply be to update your BeautifulSoup install; it's been closed for three years.

Comment: I mean its the same problem but I'm on the latest BeautifulSoup version 4.4.0.

Comment: Is decaying the tags you want to remove not an option?

Comment: Decomposing would be fine too, but the error is deeper I think.  I get the same error with this:
            for code in soup.findAll('code'):
                for c in code.children:
                    logging.debug(unicode(c))

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/).

Comment: @almccann Have you learned anything since?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Any fix for this? I'm still encountering the bug

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had encountered this problem and browsed a lot of web pages. I summary two methods to solve this problem.

However, I think we should know why that happened. Python limits the number of recursive(default number is 1000). We can see this number with `print sys.getrecursionlimit()`. I guess that **BeautifulSoup uses recursion to find child elements**. When recursion is more than 1000 times, `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` will appear.

**First method:** use `sys.setrecursionlimit()` set limited number of recursive. You obviously can set 1000000, but maybe cause `segmentation fault`.

**Second Method:** use `try-except`. If appeared  `maximum recursion depth exceeded`, Our algorithm might have problems. Generally speaking, we can use loops instead of recursion. In your question, we could deal with HTML with `replace()` or regular expression in advance.

Finally, I give an example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys   
#sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

try:
    doc = ''.join(['<br>' for x in range(1000)])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
    a = soup.find('br')
    for i in a:
        print i
except:
    print 'failed'
```

If removed the `#`, it could print `doc`.

Hoping to help you.

Comment: But why would there be 1000 recursions for OP's sample code?

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure about why this works (I haven't examined the source), but adding `.text` or `.get_text()` seems to bypass the error for me.

For instance, changing

`lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')`

to

`lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').get_text()` seems to work without throwing a recursion depth error.

Comment: Adding `.get_text()` to `BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')` turns the document from `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` to `<class 'str'>`. Turning your whole document into a string doesn't feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I've been dealing with this error recently.
I noticed I was not using the last version of BeautifulSoup, so I upgraded it to 4.12.2 and the problem solved.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade
```

I presume it was a bug, given that it doesn't make sense that it fails if the HTML has multiple nested nodes. It's a library designed to work with HTML, you should be able to feed it with any HTML and it shouldn't raise an error like that one. I was using version 4.11.2, but I upgraded it to 4.12.2 and the problem was solved.